# How can I create a new user through terminal macOS 10.14

Tags: macos, terminal, unix, mojave, user-account

I am trying to write a script to add a user to a computer. These will not be admin accounts and should be staff accounts. I ran the following script and can login to the account but I can't access any files, create any files, or save any files to the computer.

Ultimately I would like to run this to remove 5 user accounts and all of their information and then create 5 new accounts (this is in a classroom where I have 36 computers) but I am struggling to create a single user correctly with the following script.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=per1
FULLNAME="Period 1"
PASSWORD="test"
SECONDARY_GROUPS="staff" 

# ====

if [[ $UID -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Please run $0 as root." && exit 1; fi

# Find out the next available user ID
MAXID=$(dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2}' | sort -ug | tail -1)
USERID=$((MAXID+1))

# Create the user account
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME RealName "$FULLNAME"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID "$USERID"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /Users/$USERNAME

dscl . -passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PASSWORD


# Add use to any specified groups
for GROUP in $SECONDARY_GROUPS ; do
    dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a $USERNAME $GROUP
done

# Create the home directory
createhomedir -c > /dev/null

echo "Created user #$USERID: $USERNAME ($FULLNAME)"
```

Comment: Where/how exactly does the script not do what you want it to do?

Comment: This is creating a user but I believe there is an issue with the home directory creation. Perhaps a permission issue. For instance I can not view any folder in finder.

Comment: I get this error while logged in to the account created: The folder "Desktop" can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents.

Comment: Well, without looking at everything in detail: How do you expect `createhomedir` to know for which user it should create a home directory?

Comment: Thank you! I added the user and the script works now

Comment: A couple of additional recommendations for the script: You don't need to add `staff` as a secondary group, since it's already being set as the users' primary group (staff is group #20). Also, I recommend using lower- or mixed-case for your shell and environment variables, since there are a bunch of all-caps variables (like `$PATH`, `$USER`, `$UID`, etc) that have special meanings, and if you accidentally reuse one of those for something else, it can cause problems.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=per1
FULLNAME="Period 1"
PASSWORD="test"
SECONDARY_GROUPS="staff" 

# ====

if [[ $UID -ne 0 ]]; then echo "Please run $0 as root." && exit 1; fi

# Find out the next available user ID
MAXID=$(dscl . -list /Users UniqueID | awk '{print $2}' | sort -ug | tail -1)
USERID=$((MAXID+1))

# Create the user account
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UserShell /bin/bash
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME RealName "$FULLNAME"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME UniqueID "$USERID"
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME PrimaryGroupID 20
dscl . -create /Users/$USERNAME NFSHomeDirectory /Users/$USERNAME

dscl . -passwd /Users/$USERNAME $PASSWORD


# Add use to any specified groups
for GROUP in $SECONDARY_GROUPS ; do
    dseditgroup -o edit -t user -a $USERNAME $GROUP
done

# Create the home directory
createhomedir -c -u $USERNAME > /dev/null

echo "Created user #$USERID: $USERNAME ($FULLNAME)"
```

Comment: The difference between the original script and this one here is the addition of `-u $USERNAME` to the `createhomedir` command.

Answer (score 0):

John Vincents answer is very useful as it can create the user for you via a script...

You will also want to consider secureToken status creation for the new user as well if you plan on activating FileVault for the user.

Some more important information regarding SecureToken:
https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2018/01/20/secure-token-and-filevault-on-apple-file-system/

You can add the secureToken using the following with root:

```
sysadminctl -adminUser root -adminPassword <rootPassword> -secureTokenOn <user> -password <userPassword>
```

You can check secureToken status this way:

```
sysadminctl -secureTokenStatus username_goes_here
```