# Is Disk Partitioning User Data Sensible in Catalina?

Tags: partition, apfs

I'm a first time mac owner (coming from Linux and Windows) and so far I'm enjoying myself. =) Big fan of the Unix roots in a polished package.

I typically partition my system's "disk" drive to include a separate Data partition where I store all my active projects and personal data (on Linux, this would mean mounting `/home` to a separate partition).

I was about to do the same on my macbook, but realized there is already some volume segregation via APFS volume groups. However, I don't know if this has the same effects or not.

So my question is this: If I totally bork my OS somehow and want to completely reinstall from scratch, will the separate APFS volume be untouched?

It seems like the purpose is not for this but instead to prevent user apps from accessing the read-only system partition. So to me, it seems as if I should indeed create a separate partition so that any potential reinstall operations would not touch my personal data.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I haven't experimented under Catalina, but my past experience is that putting home folders on a separate volume tends to cause more trouble than it avoids. Instead, I'd recommend keeping good backups that you can restore from if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> If I totally bork my OS somehow and want to completely reinstall from scratch, will the separate APFS volume be untouched?

You are talking [About the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650) changes and no, the data volume will not be totally untouched.  If you completely reinstall macOS from scratch it will be overwritten.

The *Macintosh HD - Data* volume is not really analogous to `/home` as it contains caches, logs, `/usr/local` and other non-static parts of the OS.  The *Macintosh HD* read only volume contains only things that don't change (by definition). When you do a re-install **all** of this is overwritten.

Here is what the data volume contains (from *The Eclectic Light Company* [Catalina Boot Volumes](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/01/23/catalina-boot-volumes/) page).

[image: Data Volume Layout]

> So to me, it seems as if I should indeed create a separate partition so that any potential reinstall operations would not touch my personal data

That is a matter of opinion.  If you didn't reinstall everything the same you could end up with things in `~/Library` that no-longer matched what was installed. The same as could happen after reinstalling with regard to config files on Linux (after relocating `/home`) or *%AppData%* on Windows (after relocating `/Users`).

You may find it more convenient to simply use data volumes outside of `/Users` for your data or to restore your data from backup after a reinstall.  It depends how big your data are and how often you plan to reinstall I suppose.

If you want to though you can update the location of your users home directory to be on another volume.  This location is stored in the directory services database in `/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/user` and can be updated by either

- *System Preferences > Users and groups* **or**
- `sudo dscl . create /Users/yourUser NFSHomeDirectory /new/path/yourUser` **or**
- [Directory Utility](https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/set-up-home-folders-for-user-accounts-diru31ab8054/mac)

A new folder hierarchy will then be automatically created at the new location when the user next logs on.  See [Relocating /Users folder in MacOS 10.15 (Catalina)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374589/relocating-users-folder-in-macos-10-15-catalina).

Then after a complete re-install it would just be a matter of updating the location again to point to the other volume containing your existing data.

Comment: Some nitpicking: it's rather the (local) Directory Services "database" (/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/...) which is updated **with** System Preferences.app > Users & Groups (**or** Directory Services.app).

Comment: @klanomath - good point! I've updated with your comments.