# Is there a simple way to put a Catalina user folder on a external volume and be able to clone/BU using TNM/CCC?

Tags: backup, time-machine, catalina, alias, carbon-copy-cloner

i was hoping to ask if there a simple way to put a Catalina user folder on a external volume and be able to clone/BU using Time machine or CarbonCopy Cloner etc

I read some comments about using the terminal or a symlink app but the answers/Info where mixed..

Any advise appreciated

Comment: "Putting a user folder on a external drive" and "Cloning/backup via TM or CCC" seem to be two different things, so it's a bit unclear what you want to accomplish here. Can you describe the problem to be solved in more details?

Comment: Also, if you already looked at related questions/answers, please add links so people don't recomend the same thing again.

Comment: [This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374590/9058) seems to address the same problem, would this work for you?

Comment: no, I simply want to use a larger external drive with my MacBoook cause catalina insist some programs have to be installed in the internal drive, maybe I can install a os external altogether but that would be even weirder no? could it cause problems